# Passing associative array(Hashmap) as parameter to xml rpc

Tags: java, xml, xml-rpc

I want to XML-RPC from Java,I am facing problem while passing associative array(Hashmap) as parameter.Here is my code.

```
 XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
        config.setServerURL(new URL(ServeUrl));
        XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
        client.setConfig(config);
        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put(Parameter Name, Parameter Value);
        map.put(Parameter Name , Parameter Value);
        Object result = client.execute("method name", map);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HashMap needs to be wrapped in an object array:

```
Object result = client.execute("method name", new Object [] {map});
```

Comment: I have also problem in this as in xmlrpcClient.execute it is not taking object array. Only allowed parameter is vector. Maybe I'm using some different version of the lib. What should ido ? (plzzz don't suggest to change the library as i have already implemented the most of the code)